# Rphylopars: "Error in class(tree) <- "phylo" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL"

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I'm trying to compute a phenotypic covariance matrix between a fatty acid dataset and a phylogenetic tree using the `Rphylopars` package.

I'm able to load the data set and phylogeny; however, when I attempt to run the test I get the error message

> Error in class(tree) <- "phylo" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL"

This is the code for the test

```r
phy <- read.tree("combined_trees.txt")
plot(phy)
phy$tip.label

FA_data <- read.csv("fatty_acid_example_data.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = ".")
head(FA_data)
str(FA_data)

PPE <- phylopars(trait_data = FA_data$fatty1_continuous, tree = FA_data$phy)
```

Not sure what other info will help figure out the issue. The data set and phylogeny loaded without an error.

Comment: Guessing, but I think it should just be `tree = phy` ?

Comment: I'm using code from the tutorial: http://www.rphylopars.org/tutorial.html 
It's step 3. I think the idea is to pair the dataset with the tree

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the [tutorial](http://www.rphylopars.org/tutorial.html), the tree and trait data are jointly simulated by the `simtraits()` function, so both end up as elements of a single list.  In your case (which will be typical of real-data cases), the tree and the trait data come from different sources, so *most likely* you want

```r
PPE <- phylopars(trait_data = FA_data, tree = phy)
```

provided that `FA_data` contains a first column `species` matching the tip names in `phy`, and otherwise only the numeric data you want to use (potentially only the single `fatty_acid1` column).

For comparison, the data structure returned by `simtraits()` looks like this (using `str()`):

```r
List of 4
 $ trait_data:'data.frame': 45 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ species: chr [1:45] "t7" "t8" "t2" "t3" ...
  ..$ V1     : num [1:45] 1.338 0.308 1.739 2.009 2.903 ...
  ..$ V2     : num [1:45] -2.002 -0.115 -0.349 -4.452 NA ...
  ..$ V3     : num [1:45] -1.74 NA 1.09 -2.54 -1.19 ...
  ..$ V4     : num [1:45] 2.496 2.712 1.198 1.675 -0.117 ...
 $ tree      :List of 4
  ..$ edge       : int [1:28, 1:2] 29 29 28 28 27 27 26 26 25 25 ...
  ..$ edge.length: num [1:28] 0.0941 0.0941 0.6233 0.7174 0.0527 ...
  ..$ Nnode      : int 14
  ..$ tip.label  : chr [1:15] "t7" "t8" "t2" "t3" ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
  ..- attr(*, "order")= chr "postorder"
...
```

you can see that `simtraits()` returns a list containing (among other things) (1) a data frame *with `species` as the first column and the other columns numeric* and (2) a phylogenetic tree.

You